# Error plotting chart with facet_wrap and scales = "free" in plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have a time series with various categories (facets), and I am trying to create a chart using the `facet_wrap` feature from `ggplot2` and upload it on `plotly`.

If I set `scales = "fixed"`, I have no problem: the graph looks fine on my computer and on `plotly`. But if I set `scales = "free"`, as in the code below, then the `ggplot2` on my computer looks fine, but the `plotly` version is not showing up properly (either on my computer or the web).

Here is some sample code; I create some random values for 12 states covering a 16-year period from 2000 to 2015, and I want to plot a time series of those values with each state having its own chart and unique y-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

set.seed(1) 
states = sample(state.name, 12) ## create random list of 12 states 

## create random data with values for state and by year 
dat <- data.frame(Year = rep(2000:2015, times = 12),
              State = rep(states, each = 16),
              Value = rnorm((12*16), mean = 5, sd = 2))

## plot data with facet_wrap for each state
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(Year, Value)) + geom_line() + 
    facet_wrap(~ State, ncol = 4, scales = "free")
p
ggplotly(p)
```

The `ggplot2` command (p) shows up as expected:

[image]

But the `ggplotly(p)` is distorted:

[image]

As far as I can tell, there was a previous thread on this topic, but it was not resolved:

[Plotly Facets not translating properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886907/plotly-facets-not-translating-properly)

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I hope this is resolved using ggplot soon... I'm having the same problem, and want to stick with ggplot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to an alternative, you could try with native `plotly` with `subplot`. Try:

```
dat$id <- as.integer(dat$State)
p <- plot_ly(dat, x = Year, y = Value, group = State,
             xaxis = paste0("x", id), marker=list(color="black"))
p <- layout(
    subplot(p, nrows=3, margin = 0.05),
    xaxis = list(title = "Arizona"),
    xaxis2 = list(title = "Connecticut"),
    xaxis3 = list(title = "Florida"),
    xaxis4 = list(title = "Georgia"),
    xaxis5 = list(title = "Indiana"),
    xaxis6 = list(title = "Maine"),
    xaxis7 = list(title = "Nebraska"),
    xaxis8 = list(title = "Nevada"),
    xaxis9 = list(title = "New Hampshire"),
    xaxis10 = list(title = "South Dakota"),
    xaxis11 = list(title = "Tennessee"),
    xaxis12 = list(title = "Texas"), 

    yaxis = list(title = "Value"),
    yaxis2 = list(title = ""),
    yaxis3 = list(title = ""),
    yaxis4 = list(title = ""),
    yaxis5 = list(title = "Value"),
    yaxis6 = list(title = ""),
    yaxis7 = list(title = ""),
    yaxis8 = list(title = ""),
    yaxis9 = list(title = "Value"),
    yaxis10 = list(title = ""),
    yaxis11 = list(title = ""),
    yaxis12 = list(title = ""), showlegend = FALSE)
p
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that suggestion -- I shied away from subplot because it seemed to require a bit more specification, but it might be the only way. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: if it turns out to be the solution for you, don't forget to accept the answer or +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Came across very similar issue with ggplotly if not exact the same cause. (After many years) What made a difference for me is **removing the `ncol` argument** within `facet_wrap()`, or find a value it likes... It could be an issue with the arrangement with subplot but not 100% sure.