# Converting ggplot graph with ggplotly function

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have got a shiny application where I use the plotly package to convert my ggplot graph into dynamics graphics. 
I am at the moment facing a problem with this conversion.

Here is my data.frame :

```
b <- data.frame(ID_Miseq = c(rep("P1",8), rep("P2",8), rep("P3",8), rep("P4",8)),
Condition1 = c(rep("A", 8), rep("B",16), rep("C", 8)),
Taxon = c(rep(paste0("T",1:8),4)),
Percent = sample(seq(1,25,0.1),32))
```

When I am creating my static barplot, no problem.

```
library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(b, aes(x = ID_Miseq, y = Percent, fill = Taxon))
gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
factors <- "~Condition1"
gg <- gg + facet_grid(factors, scales = "free", space = "free_x")
gg
```

[image: Output from ggplot2]

But, when I am using the ggplotly function from the plotly package, one of the sample is turning into numeric scale.

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

Does anyone have ever faced the same kind of issue ? Am I using the ggplotly function wrong ? I am using plotly 4.7.1

Comment: This problem has been already reported on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660991/plot-ly-faceting-trellis-panel-label-and-fixed-height/45695265#45695265

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plot\_ly faceting/trellis panel label and fixed height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660991/plot-ly-faceting-trellis-panel-label-and-fixed-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, this is now fixed in the dev version, https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/commit/a0fc9c93e3b64ef4545b3522abbdfe44dc0e81a3

Install the dev version with `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")`