# R Markdown: My plotly graph is getting cropped

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-markdown

as I tried to view my plotly graph in an R Markdown format from my R Studio, it gets cropped in the situation below.

[image]

My original graph is supposed to be like this:

[image]

However when I try to convert it to plotly to be able to be published in R Markdown, this happens to my graph.

What changes I could make to my code?

```
#Load Libaries

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
options(scipen = 100000)
library(scales)
library(stringr)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

#Read dataset
ura <- read.csv('URAdata_new.csv') 

#Data cleaning
ura <- ura %>% mutate(Date.of.Sale_month = str_split(ura$Date.of.Sale, '-', simplify = T)[, 1],
               Date.of.Sale_year = str_split(ura$Date.of.Sale, '-', simplify = T)[, 2])

#Plotly Graph in issue
  

Plot2<-ggplotly(ura %>%
  separate(Date.of.Sale, c('Sale_year', 'Sale_month'), sep = '-') %>%
  filter(Sale_year %in% c(16, 17) & Postal.District %in% c(2, 5)) %>%
  group_by(Sale_year, Postal.District) %>%
  summarize(avg_price = mean(Price....)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.character(Postal.District), y = avg_price, 
             fill = as.factor(Sale_year))) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(~ as.factor(Sale_year)) +
  labs(x = 'Postal District', y = 'Average price', 
       title = 'Comparison of unit prices in district 2 and 5 between 2016 and 2017') +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Year of sale", labels = c("2016", "2017"))+
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(colour="red",size=14, face="bold.italic",hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_text(colour="blue",size=14, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(colour="green",size=14, face="bold"))+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Average Price",labels = comma), main="foo")

Plot2
```

This is the problem with the graph when I convert it to plotly. Everything gets disorganized and falls short of aesthetic.

What changes to my code can I make? Please advise.

[image]

dput(head(ura,20))

```
structure(list(Project.Name = c("V ON SHENTON", "V ON SHENTON", 
"STIRLING RESIDENCES", "PARC CLEMATIS", "STIRLING RESIDENCES", 
"ONE PEARL BANK", "TWIN VEW", "WHISTLER GRAND", "WHISTLER GRAND", 
"WHISTLER GRAND", "WHISTLER GRAND", "WHISTLER GRAND", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", 
"KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", 
"KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", 
"STIRLING RESIDENCES"), Street.Name = c("SHENTON WAY", "SHENTON WAY", 
"STIRLING ROAD", "JALAN LEMPENG", "STIRLING ROAD", "PEARL BANK", 
"WEST COAST VALE", "WEST COAST VALE", "WEST COAST VALE", "WEST COAST VALE", 
"WEST COAST VALE", "WEST COAST VALE", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", 
"SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", 
"SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", 
"STIRLING ROAD"), Type = c("Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", 
"Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", 
"Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", 
"Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", 
"Apartment", "Apartment"), Postal.District = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L
), Market.Segment = c("CCR", "CCR", "RCR", "OCR", "RCR", "RCR", 
"OCR", "OCR", "OCR", "OCR", "OCR", "OCR", "RCR", "RCR", "RCR", 
"RCR", "RCR", "RCR", "RCR", "RCR"), Tenure = c("99 yrs lease commencing from 2011", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2011", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2017", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2019", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2017", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2019", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2017", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2017"), Type.of.Sale = c("Resale", 
"Resale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", 
"New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", 
"New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", 
"New Sale"), No..of.Units = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Price.... = c(3548000L, 
3490000L, 1987000L, 1745000L, 1227000L, 1702000L, 1899000L, 704380L, 
1129960L, 1145540L, 1473540L, 1421880L, 1367000L, 1360000L, 3000000L, 
870000L, 1711000L, 899000L, 870000L, 1249000L), Nett.Price.... = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Area..Sqft. = c(1518L, 1518L, 
1055L, 1044L, 635L, 700L, 1249L, 441L, 764L, 764L, 990L, 958L, 
775L, 786L, 1776L, 484L, 958L, 484L, 484L, 635L), Type.of.Area = c("Strata", 
"Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", 
"Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", 
"Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata"), Floor.Level = c("46 to 50", 
"46 to 50", "26 to 30", "06 to 10", "31 to 35", "21 to 25", "26 to 30", 
"21 to 25", "21 to 25", "21 to 25", "31 to 35", "31 to 35", "01 to 05", 
"01 to 05", "01 to 05", "01 to 05", "01 to 05", "01 to 05", "01 to 05", 
"16 to 20"), Unit.Price...psf. = c(2338L, 2299L, 1884L, 1671L, 
1932L, 2433L, 1521L, 1596L, 1479L, 1499L, 1488L, 1484L, 1764L, 
1731L, 1689L, 1796L, 1786L, 1856L, 1796L, 1967L), Date.of.Sale = c("20-Jun", 
"20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", 
"20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", 
"20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Google Sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QFXNUpgEjjPGdfXUwvzYIadnoxcD2-Ba6cw6BqrxfO8/edit

My full R Markdown code:

````
---
title: "**Individual PA2 CA2**"
author: "***Submitted by: Chua Shao Yang***"
date: "***22 January 2021***"
output: 
  html_document:
  toc: true
runtime: shiny
---
<style type="text/css">

h1.title {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: Black;
  text-align: center;
}
h4.author { /* Header 4 - and the author and data headers use this too  */
    font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: DarkRed;
  text-align: center;
}
h4.date { /* Header 4 - and the author and data headers use this too  */
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: DarkBlue;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
#Load the relevant libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

options(scipen=10000)

#Load and read the dataset
ura <- read.csv('URAdata_new.csv') 
```

### <span style="color:green">Background</span> {#css_id}

In Singapore, there are two types of property types we are assessing in this report: apartment and condominium. 

### <span style="color:green">Price Appreciation of Property Types</span> {#css_id}

Pending more information to be written here.


```{r, message=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

Plot1<-ggplotly(ura %>% 
  group_by(Type.of.Sale) %>% 
  summarize(avg_price = mean(Price....)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Type.of.Sale, y = avg_price, fill = Type.of.Sale)) + 
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = 'Type of sale', 
       y = 'Average price', 
       title = 'Average price across different types of sales') +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Type of sale", 
                      labels = c("New Sale", "Resale", "Sub Sale"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(colour="red",size=14, face="bold.italic",hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_text(colour="blue",size=14, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(colour="green",size=14, face="bold")) + 
    scale_y_continuous(name="Average Price",labels = scales::comma, limits = c(0, 2500000)))
  
Plot1

```

#### <span style="color:green">Insight 1</span> {#css_id}

Pending more information to be written here.

### <span style="color:green">Graph Description</span> {#css_id}

Pending more information to be written here.

#### <span style="color:green">Insight 2</span> {#css_id}

Pending more information to be written here.


```{r, message = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

Plot2<-ggplotly(ura %>%
  separate(Date.of.Sale, c('Sale_year', 'Sale_month'), sep = '-') %>%
  filter(Sale_year %in% c(16, 17) & Postal.District %in% c(2, 5)) %>%
  group_by(Sale_year, Postal.District) %>%
  summarize(avg_price = mean(Price....)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.character(Postal.District), y = avg_price, 
             fill = as.factor(Sale_year))) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(~ as.factor(Sale_year)) +
  labs(x = 'Postal District', y = 'Average price', 
       title = 'Comparison of unit prices in district 2 and 5 between 2016 and 2017') +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Year of sale", labels = c("2016", "2017"))+
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(colour="red",size=14, face="bold.italic",hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_text(colour="blue",size=14, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(colour="green",size=14, face="bold"))+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Average Price",labels = comma), main="foo")

Plot2

```
````

Comment: I can provide the dput() or a google link. Check back soon as I edit the question first

Comment: I have made the changes although I am not sure what you meant by question is self-contained

Comment: I have edited the codes for the graph part. Look out for Plot 2.

Comment: Can you post your YAML? The problem might be there. EDIT: And your chunk options.

Comment: I can add my whole markdown code

Comment: I have put it under the section my full markdown code

Comment: I found an answer that might not help solving your issue, but it should help you understand where the problem is coming from :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301879/plotly-and-ggplot-with-facet-grid-in-r-how-to-to-get-yaxis-labels-to-use-tickte

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust size of plot title and legend title.

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

Plot2 <- ggplotly(ura %>%
           separate(Date.of.Sale, c('Sale_year', 'Sale_month'), sep = '-') %>%
           filter(Sale_year %in% c(16, 17) & Postal.District %in% c(2, 5)) %>%
           group_by(Sale_year, Postal.District) %>%
           summarize(avg_price = mean(Price....)) %>%
           ggplot(aes(x = as.character(Postal.District), y = avg_price, 
                      fill = as.factor(Sale_year))) + 
           geom_col() + 
           facet_grid(~ as.factor(Sale_year)) +
           labs(x = 'Postal District', y = 'Average price', 
                title = 'Comparison of unit prices in district 2 and 5 between 2016 and 2017') +
           scale_fill_discrete(name = "Year of sale", labels = c("2016", "2017"))+
           theme(
             plot.title = element_text(colour="red",size=10, face="bold.italic",hjust = 0.5),
             axis.title.x = element_text(colour="blue",size=14, face="bold"),
             axis.title.y = element_text(colour="green",size=14, face="bold"), 
             legend.title=element_text(size=8))+
           scale_y_continuous(name="Average Price",labels = comma), main="foo")
Plot2
```

[image]

You can play around with `size` in `plot.title` and `legend.title=element_text(size=8)` and see what fits best on your device.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to adjust the x and y axis title as they are interfering with my y and x axis values. Can I also adjust my chart title space between the graph to be larger as it is very close to my graph

Comment: Have you tried options available here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487188/increase-distance-between-text-and-title-on-the-y-axis ?

Comment: I tried margin on my x axis and title but nothing working

Comment: Not sure then. Perhaps, you can ask that as a new question since this was related plot and legend title.