# ggplotly removing data from single facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to create a plotly graph for a shiny app. I am running into an issue with certain layouts of faceted plots. Whenever there are four facets and they are in a 2x2 grid, the bottom left facet does not display any data even though the data is there in the `ggplot` figure. This also happens when there are 6 facets in a 3x2 grid, with the bottom left again being dropped. The examples on the [plotly ggplot examples page](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/facet/) show several examples with a 2x2 grid and the data being displayed. I am not sure what the issue is. Any help is much appreciated.

**Code:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

data %>%
  filter(!is.na(result)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date_time, result)) +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()


ggplotly()
```

**`ggplot` output:**
[image: <code>ggplot</code> output]

**`ggplotly` output:**
[image: <code>ggplotly</code> output]

**Data:**

```
data <- structure(list(group = c("w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", 
                                 "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", 
                                 "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w", 
                                 "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
                                 "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", 
                                 "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
                                 "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
                                 "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", 
                                 "x", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", 
                                 "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", 
                                 "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z", "z"), 
                   date_time = structure(c(1501581060, 1501668000, 1501752000, 
                                           1501837740, 1502101200, 1502184600, 1502271840, 
                                           1502357280, 1502442720, 1502701860, 1502789280, 
                                           1502876340, 1502961600, 1503047640, 1503305520, 
                                           1503394200, 1503480900, 1503567600, 1503651300, 
                                           1503915120, 1503997800, 1504086300, 1504171920, 
                                           1504259100, 1504607100, 1504691040, 1504777500,
                                           1504865820, 1505122680, 1505211600, 1505296560, 
                                           1505382720, 1505470140, 1501581060, 1501668000, 
                                           1501752000, 1501837740, 1502101200, 1502184600, 
                                           1502271840, 1502357280, 1502442720, 1502701860, 
                                           1502789280, 1502876340, 1502961600, 1503047640, 
                                           1503305520, 1503394200, 1503480900, 1503567600, 
                                           1503651300, 1503915120, 1503997800, 1504086300, 
                                           1504171920, 1504259100, 1504607100, 1504691040, 
                                           1504777500, 1504865820, 1505122680, 1505211600, 
                                           1505296560, 1505382720, 1505470140, 1501581060, 
                                           1501668000, 1501752000, 1501837740, 1502101200, 
                                           1502184600, 1502271840, 1502357280, 1502442720, 
                                           1502701860, 1502789280, 1502876340, 1502961600, 
                                           1503047640, 1503305520, 1503394200, 1503480900, 
                                           1503567600, 1503651300, 1503915120, 1503997800, 
                                           1504086300, 1504171920, 1504259100, 1504607100, 
                                           1504691040, 1504777500, 1504865820, 1505122680, 
                                           1505211600, 1505296560, 1505382720, 1505470140, 
                                           1501581060, 1501668000, 1501752000, 1501837740, 
                                           1502101200, 1502184600, 1502271840, 1502357280, 
                                           1502442720, 1502701860, 1502789280, 1502876340, 
                                           1502961600, 1503047640, 1503305520, 1503394200, 
                                           1503480900, 1503567600, 1503651300, 1503915120, 
                                           1503997800, 1504086300, 1504171920, 1504259100, 
                                           1504607100, 1504691040, 1504777500, 1504865820, 
                                           1505122680, 1505211600, 1505296560, 1505382720, 
                                           1505470140), 
                                         class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                   result = c(2.1, 1.75, 1.65, 1.65,  1.75, 1.65, 1.3, 1.65, 1.9, 1.6, 1.65, 
                              1.35, 1.6, 1.85, 2.05,  1.95, 2, 1.95, 1.9, 1.9, 2.05, 2, 2, 
                              2, 2.1, 2.1, 2, 2.05, 2.05, 2.3, 2.2, 2, NA, 7.14, 7.1, 7.09, 
                              7.09, 7.13, 7.12, 7.13, 7.07, 7.04, 7.06, 7.12, 7.08, 7.06, 
                              7.07, 7.05, 7.05, 7.1, 7.09, 7.06, 7.18, 7.16, 7.11, 7.17, 
                              7.14, 7.13, 7.08, 7.11, 7.09, 7.12, 7.05,  7.08, 7.02, 7.12, 
                              0.214, 0.181, 0.357, 0.49, 0.294, 0.369, 0.406, 0.325, 0.197, 
                              0.36, 0.358, 0.408, 0.37, 0.254, 0.24, 0.178, 0.201, 0.166, 0.203, 
                              0.163, 0.147, 0.177, 0.155, 0.177, 0.133, 0.133, 0.182, 0.203, 
                              0.161, 0.151, 0.171, 0.117, NA, 26, 26, 26, 26, 25, 26, 25, 26, 
                              26, 26, 26, 25, 26, 26, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 25, 
                              25, 24, 24, 24, 23, 23, 23, 24, 23)), 
              .Names = c("group", "date_time", "result"), 
              class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
              row.names = c(NA, -132L))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably this is a bug in `ggplotly`.
A solution is to use `scales="free"` inside `facet_wrap` and then to manually define the common x axes for the 4 plots.

```
p <- data %>%
  filter(!is.na(result)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date_time, result)) +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()

g <- plotly_build(p)
# Set "x3" axis as common x-axis of Plot 1 and 3 
g$x$data[[1]]$xaxis <- "x3"
# Set "x4" axis as common x-axis of Plot 2 and 4
g$x$data[[2]]$xaxis <- "x4"
print(g)
```

[image]
Other solutions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736103/error-plotting-chart-with-facet-wrap-and-scales-free-in-plotly) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886907/plotly-facets-not-translating-properly).

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there no way to do this with a fixed x axis? I would prefer the data to be aligned by the date and time for comparison.

Comment: In this example, yes, the data are fairly close. But if you look closely at the right plots, you will see that the gridline for "Sept 15" is not aligned exactly. This problem will be more of an issue if the date ranges of the groups are not exactly the same, which could be an issue with my actual data