# When using ggplotly with facet_wrap, only the data of the first facet appears

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, ggplotly

I am plotting boxplots for multiple groups using `ggplot() + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap()`. I would like to use `ggplotly()` on this object to use the hover tooltips so that I can quickly review data associated with the outliers. (Why am I not just annotating on the plot? I will add custom text to the tooltip that is more extensive than I would like to appear in a fixed annotation on the plot.)

When I use `ggplotly`, the facets are displayed but only the data of the first facet appears. The same is true with `facet_grid`. (I would prefer to use `facet_wrap` so that I can use free scales between different facets.)

Is there a way to get `ggplotly` to work with facets this way? I don't see anything in the [ggplotly documentation](https://plotly.com/ggplot2/facet_grid/). I've seen other examples where people have [other issues with their facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263918/ggplotly-not-working-properly-when-number-are-facets-are-more) but all the facets are there.

```
# make data: 
# B: normal distribution divided across 3 groups
# C: group Z is on a different scale
df <- data.frame(A = rep(LETTERS[seq( from = 24, to = 26 )], 26*5),
                 B = rnorm(26*15))
df <- df %>% mutate(C = ifelse(A == 'Z', B*7, 
                               ifelse(A == 'Y', B + 7, B)))

# plot using facet_wrap
pwrap <- ggplot(df, aes(y = C)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(facets = 'A')
# ggplot object shows fine
pwrap
```

[image]

```
# ggplotly object only shows first facet
ggplotly(pwrap)
```

[image]

```
# plot using facet_grid
pgrid <- ggplot(df, aes(y = C)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_grid(.~A)
# again, ggplot object shows fine
pgrid
# but ggplotly object is limited to first facet
ggplotly(pgrid)

# my goal: facet_wrap to allow 'free' y-scales for variable C, with ggplotly hover info
ggplot(df, aes(y = C)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~A, scales = 'free')
```

Session info:
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)
ggExtra_0.9
plotly_4.9.3
ggplot2_3.3.3

Comment: Have you tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46281534/ggplotly-removing-data-from-single-facet ? It seems like related.

Comment: Thanks for finding the related question. I tried a bit from that question and related links and still get gaps with my data. I haven't exhausted that info yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually coming but you are unable to see it, If you `zoom out` you fill find all the plots, you can modify your code like below to make it work, Here I have changed the width to mean of the column `mean(df$C)`.
On a side note you can make it better by using `scales='free'` in the `facet_wrap(facets = 'A', scales='free')` command, but in that case you have three vertical axis.

```
pwrap <- ggplot(df, aes(y = C)) +
  geom_boxplot(width=mean(abs(df$C))) +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(facets = 'A')
# ggplot object shows fine
pwrap
ggplotly(pwrap)
```

Another version (scaled version), using x = 1 and scales='free' and without using the width option, The difference in both the plots is that the second plot is centered(plot is not attached), Please let me know if it helped:

```
# plot using facet_wrap
pwrap <- ggplot(df, aes(x = 'X', y = C)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~A, scales='free') 
# ggplot object shows fine
pwrap
ggplotly(pwrap)
```

**Output from first version**:

[image]

Comment: This is interesting because it points out why my previous attempts were failing: the changing x value with each group. I don't understand why x indexes by 1 for each facet in the ggplotly object, even in your second version with a defined constant x value. I suppose I could define an x-axis transformation for each facet.

Comment: I don't see anything about this in the [documentation] (https://plotly.com/ggplot2/box-plots/)

Comment: Actually, combining the documentation and PKumar's suggestion led to a solution: x needs to be a factor. See solution.

Answer (score 2):

PKumar's solution is close (defining x variable), but the x axis was still not behaving as I expected. The solution is to make sure the x variable is a factor.

```
# plot using facet_wrap
pwrap <- ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(A), y = C)) + # x is a factor (as.factor('X') also OK if trying to match PKumar's answer)
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~A, scales='free') 

# ggplot object
pwrap

# now a functional 
ggplotly(pwrap)
```

[image]